# Monitor google app engine cron jobs in console?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cron, refresh, jobs

This might be a dumb question, but, i just can't find cron jobs panel, I've got an app in java and I need to refresh the data every day, so I create this cron.xml inside WEB-INF:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cronentries>
    <cron>
        <url>/refreshdata</url>
        <description>Daily data refresh cron task </description>
        <schedule>every day 05:00</schedule>
    </cron>
</cronentries>
```

I deployed it, but it doesnt work and I cant find the "cron job panel" in console to monitor it or even check if GAE recognizes it...

Documentation says " (You can verify the Cron job you just deployed by clicking Cron Jobs in the left nav pane.) https://i.stack.imgur.com/1niVt.png "

but it doesn't exist anymore, gae's console UI changed, where it is now? I tried in logs without success

it is something wrong with my .xml?

Any help would be apreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image]

If you are using the new Console for your projects in app engine then this is how it will look like after you have selected a project to view from https://console.developers.google.com/project using your google account.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can find it under Task Queues, you should be able to see Cron as a tab in that view

Answer (score 0):

On Cloud developers console, it should be available at this location:

https://console.developers.google.com/project/your-project-id/appengine/taskqueues?tab=CRON